# equation of major axis of an ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

What is the equation of 3 major axes of the following ellipsoid?
$$
\begin{pmatrix}x & y & z\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 & \beta_3 & \beta_2\\
\beta_3 & \alpha_2 & \beta_1\\
\beta_2 & \beta_1  & \alpha_3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} = 1\tag{1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your equation can be rewritten as
$$
\mathbf{x}^\top\Sigma\mathbf{x}=1,
$$
where $\mathbf{x}=(x, y, z)^\top$, and 
$$
\Sigma = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 & \beta_3 & \beta_2\\
\beta_3 & \alpha_2 & \beta_1\\
\beta_2 & \beta_1  & \alpha_3
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
If you take the SVD (Singular Value Decomposition) of $\Sigma$ you will have
$$
\Sigma = VDV^\top,
$$
where $D$ is the diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of $\Sigma$, and $V$ is an orthonormal matrix, which contains the axes (its columns). Say, 
$$
D=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3).
$$
The lengths of the axes are given as 
$$
a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_1}},
b = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_2}},
c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_3}}.
$$
Then, you can have your ellipsoid in the following form:
$$
\Big(\frac{x}{a}\Big)^2 + \Big(\frac{y}{b}\Big)^2 + \Big(\frac{z}{c}\Big)^2 = 1.
$$

**EDIT:**
If you need just the axes, then you can find them in the columns of $V$.

Comment: For the SVD of $3\times 3$ matrices, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372224/fast-method-for-computing-3x3-symmetric-matrix-spectral-decomposition, or https://github.com/smidm/Singular-Value-Decomposition, or just find the eigenvalues you need! Hope my answer helps!